# Dialog Window for configuration in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i'm relative new to MVVM. My current problem is a modular dialog which should "autostart" at the beginning.

I've followed the example of WAFs Email Client for modular dialogs. Is it right that the only important thing is to set the Owner Property of the dialog to the instance of the main window of the application (and of course show the window with ShowDialog() instead of Show()?

If you close this dialog without configuration the application will shutdown. But now, if I open the main window in visual studios designer mode the configuration dialog comes up and if I close it visual studio crashes.
This is because I call the ShowDialog() of the configuration dialog in the constructor of my main windows view model.

To avoid this i can check for DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool Property, but this is more a workaround as good code style, right?

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: maybe in future releases of VisualStudio they support MVVVM way of coding , but right now you should be satisfied with these workarounds I don't know anyway other than this DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode to prevent VisualStudio from crashing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are showing a dialog in the constructor of a class. That's something you don't want to do.
I would solve it like this:
Don't specify a `StartupUri` in your app.xaml but override `OnStartup`. There you check whether the configuration dialog should be shown or not. If it should be shown, show it and after it has closed with OK, show you main window.

Something like this:

```
override void OnStartup(...)
{
    if(configurationNotComplete)
    {
        ConfigDialog cfg = new ConfigDialog();
        if(!(cfg.ShowDialog() ?? false))
        {
            Shutdown();
            return;
        }
    }
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.Show();
}
```

You have another problem with your current approach: Your ViewModel shows a modal dialog. This means it knows at least about one View: That of the modal dialog. MVVM is one way: The View knows about the ViewModel, the ViewModel knows about the Model. There should be no connection in the other direction.

Comment: Mh code-behind? Isn't one principle of MVVM to avoid code-behind so much as possible?

Comment: Code behind in Views, yes. The application class isn't a view. Furthermore, this approach is a lot cleaner than the one you were using.

Comment: okay, and the application class can know all views? And can you explain me what are the differents between modal dialogs and "normal" dialogs, I always thought modal dialogs grays out the background and normal dialogs doesn't (because this effect is in modal dialogs in jquery).

Comment: It depends on your terminology. A modal dialog disables its parent. A "dialog" more often than not is a modal dialog. If you explicitly mean a non-modal dialog, you would say so.

Comment: This means a call to ShowDialog() makes my dialog always modal? So what's the different between non-modal dialogs and a second window, both shown by Show() methode?

Comment: ShowDialog returns after the dialog is closed, Show returns directly. A non-modal dialog is usually shown using Show.